# Proving a result for cohomology for real projective plane

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am trying to show that the cup product of any two elements in $H^{1}(\mathbb{R}P^{2};\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})$ is zero.

I have computed the cohomology groups $H^{*}(\mathbb{R}P^{2},\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})$ using the singular homology

$ \displaystyle H_{n}(\mathbb{R}P^{2}) \cong  \begin{cases} \mathbb{Z} & n =0 \\ \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} & n=1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

and the Universal Coefficient Theorem $H^{n}(\mathbb{R}P^{2};\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})\cong \operatorname{Hom}(H_{n}(\mathbb{R}P^{2}),\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})\oplus \operatorname{Ext}(H_{n-1}(\mathbb{R}P^{2}),\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})$ to get that

$ \displaystyle H^{n}(\mathbb{R}P^{2};\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}) \cong  \begin{cases} \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} & n =0 \\ \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} & n=1,2 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$.

For any to elements of $H^{1}(\mathbb{R}P^{2};\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})$ say $a,b$ we have that $a\smile b=0$. My issue is I can't really see where to get started. We have $\smile:H^{1}(\mathbb{R}P^{2};\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})\times H^{1}(\mathbb{R}P^{2};\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}) \to H^{2}(\mathbb{R}P^{2};\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})$ which one could view as $\smile:\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$... but alas I am at a loss for ideas.

Comment: Quite a tricky one. This is exercise 5 of section 3.2 in Hatcher (p. 229). Look at the hint there is you haven't seen it yet.

Answer (score 1):

$\require{AMScd}$
Consider the cellular cochain maps induced by $\phi:\Bbb Z/4\to \Bbb Z/2$.
\begin{CD}
0 @<{}<<\Bbb Z/4 @<{2}<<\Bbb Z/4 @<{0}<<\Bbb Z/4@<{}<<0\\
\text{ } @VVV @VVV @VVV\\
0@<{}<< \Bbb Z/2 @<{0}<< \Bbb Z/2@<{0}<<\Bbb Z/2 @<{}<< 0
\end{CD}
We see that the induced homomorphism is trivial for $H^1$ and bijective for $H^2$.
Consider the induced homomorphism on the cohomology rings, i.e.,
$$g:H^*(\Bbb RP^2;\Bbb Z/4)\to H^*(\Bbb RP^2;\Bbb Z/2)$$

We have $g(\alpha\smile\alpha)=g(\alpha)\smile g(\alpha)=0$ if $\alpha$ generates $H^1(\Bbb RP^2;\Bbb Z/4)$. Also, as $\alpha\smile\alpha\in H^2(\Bbb RP^2;\Bbb Z/4)$, we know that $\alpha\smile\alpha=0$ as the induced ring homomorphism is bijective in dimension $2$.

Comment: As @Кряжев stated in the comment, Hatcher's exercise is a general conclusion about coefficient $\Bbb Z/2k$. When $k=2$, the relation is direct, i.e., $\alpha^2-2\beta=\alpha^2=0$.

Comment: @KevinS How do we know that $g(a\smile a) = g(a)\smile g(a)$ here?

Comment: @Cryptokyo Because the coefficient map induces ring homomorphism on cohomology ring (whose multiplication is the cup product), we can split $g(\alpha\smile\alpha)$ into $g(\alpha)\smile g(\alpha)$.

Comment: @KevinS Ah yes I see! Thank you!

Comment: @KevinS Okay maybe I'm being a bit silly but how do we $a\smile b = 0$ from bilnearity?

Comment: @Cryptokyo We know that $H^1$ is generated by $\alpha$, so any $a,b\in H^1$ can be written as $m\alpha, n\alpha$, where $m,n\in \Bbb Z/4$. The bilinearity says $a\smile b=m\alpha\smile n\alpha=mn(\alpha\smile\alpha)=0$.

Comment: @KevinS but why then do we necessarily have $g(\alpha\smile\alpha)\Rightarrow \alpha\smile \alpha = 0$